# Why style settings for map marker is not effective in Ionic 2?

Tags: css, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic3

I used custom image for map marker but `scss` settings is not effective. I don't understand what is wrong with that.

```
 CurrentMarker(location) {
    let content: any;
    let image = 'assets/img/start.svg';
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: this.map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      position: location,
      icon: image
    });
}
```

**scss**

```
page-mapmodal {
background: rgb(229, 227, 223);

#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#map .gmnoprint img {
  width: 60px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

**the output**
As you can see marker as same size as is.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used fallowing code:

```
  var icon = {
    url: 'assets/img/target.svg', 
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50), 
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0), 
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) 
};
```